# WMI Permanent Event When PC is Shutdown

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query, meta-object-facility

I want to know if a USB key has been plugged out. This can be achieved easily using a WMI Event listener. But what if the PC is shutdown - will a WMI permanent event detect this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`WMI permanent events`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) only works while the OS is running and the WMI service is up.

Comment: so if i want to detect a usb change even when a pc is powered off how could that be done ? The only idea i can think of is to keep a list of the usb drives on a file and then compare to that file on pc bootup

Comment: Maintaining a list of connected devices can be an option.